# How can I access a global list within a entity without relation mappings?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two doctrine entities defined as below:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

   /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
    */
    private $name;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="holidays")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Holiday {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date")
     */
    private $date;

}
```

`Holiday` is a global list of holidays. There is no relation (Doctrine Mapping) between `User` and `Holiday` but I need to access holidays in user class.

How can I access holidays within user class without any mappings? I don't want to inject Entity Manager into my user class.

**Update:** Let's assume I have a method in `User` like below:

```
function getWorkedDaysExcludingHolidays() {

  // calculation $days here based on holidays

  return $days;   
}
```

Comment: I suppose you could use a doctrine life cycle listener to add in the holidays each time a user is retrieved.  But it's hard to understand why you always want the holidays injected but not use a relation.  I suppose a custom doctrine hydra-tor might also do the trick.

Comment: What you mean access - work on it on one of User entity methods? Maybe you just need to move your logic from Entity to Controller/Service?

Comment: This isn't really clear what you are asking - if there's no relation, why would you need to access in the User class?

Comment: Let's say I have a method in user class and I need to loop through holidays to do some calculation. Holidays are global for all users and doesn't belong to any users that's why there is no relation between users and holidays.

Comment: In that case I would probably pass a list of holidays (or perhaps a holiday list factory) to the method that needs them.  One would assume that most of the time the list would not be needed so it does not useful to always inject a list.

Comment: Your `User` class can't have any kind of persistent list of `Holiday` instances without save it in your `User` class. The list must be stored in order to retrieve it and then calculate your `$days`.